# How can I put all PHP Oracle error functions in one function?

Tags: php, oracle

i try to build one function hold all errors 
here is my example:

```
<?php
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "select does_not_exist from dual");
$r = oci_execute($stid);
if (!$r) {
    $e = oci_error($stid);  // For oci_execute errors pass the statement handle
    print htmlentities($e['message']);
    print "\n<pre>\n";
    print htmlentities($e['sqltext']);
    printf("\n%".($e['offset']+1)."s", "^");
    print  "\n</pre>\n";
}
?>
```

### i will lost my time if i repeat same codes with any sql query so i want make function check for error like this way

```
function error($r, $stid){
    if(!$r){
        $error = oci_error($stid);
        $code = "Code"." ".$error["code"];
        $sql = "Sql Statment"." ".$error["sqltext"];
        $Position = "Position"." ".$error["offset"];
        $message = "Message"." ".$error["message"];
        $all = array("code"=>$code, "sql"=>$sql, "Position"=>$Position, "message"=>$message);
            return($all);
        }
```

### }

I WANT TO BT LIKE THIS

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "select does_not_exist from dual");
$r = oci_execute($stid);  
$error = error($r, $stid);
echo $error["message"];
echo $error["sql"];
echo $error["code"];
echo $error["Position"];
```

but it dose not work *_* please help to do it

Answer (score 0):

`oci_error()` should be run on the connection, it's not clear from your variable names what parse is. It seems like this could be problematic. 
http://php.net/oci_error